# "Im Equipment/Mit Equipment " is this correct?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, grammaticality, article, grammar-identification

I am preparing a questionnaire to be filled in, where the person has to answer whether the battery is in the device or together with the device but not installed in it.
I asked a friend for help and got the answers:

1. "Im Equipment"
2. "Mit Equipment"

I understand "im" is a contraction of "in dem" so "with" should not be translated to "Mit dem Equipment"?

This seems illogical to me.
Shouldn't it be "in Equipment/mit Equipment" or "im Equipment/ mit dem Equipment"?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Grammar is the science of joining words together to create full sentences. Grammar is not the science of creating fragments. So, please ask a question about a full sentence, because the answer depends on what you want to use this phrase for. Both versions are correct, but in different environments.

Comment: *Batterien liegen bei*

Comment: You should not use "Equipment". It sounds awkward. Better say "Zubehör".

Comment: 'Equipment' is not a German word and could without context mean anything the reader can imagine, like in 'That's just my gear'.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Could you make an effort to write a more friendly comment?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Do you think it's unfriendly? Why?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Yes, I think it is unfriendly. You do not seem to take into account that Monika is new on german.SE So, a more welcoming tone would be better. Starting with two assertions, presented as obvious facts, gives your message an apodictic and patronizing, and hence rather repelling tone in my ears. Nicer would be, for instance: _Hey Monika! Welcome to german.SE! Both versions can be correct, depending on context. If you could provide a full sentence, this would help us to help you better._ -- Same message, but way friendier, I think.

Answer (score 1):

With the definite article, you refer to a specific device. Without an article, you refer to you might say the general concept of a device. It's similar in English:

> Das Gerät wird mit dem Equipment geliefert.

> The device will be delivered with the equipment.

compared to

> Das Gerät wird mit Equipment geliefert.

> The device will be delivered with equipment.

As a side note, from what I understand the device in question seems to be the "main point" here. So, "equipment" probably wouldn't be the best term, but rather something like "Gerät" ("device"). You could use something along the lines of

- Die Batterie ist (noch) im Gerät installiert. / The battery is (still) installed in the device.
- Die Batterie wurde aus dem Gerät entfernt und liegt bei. / The battery has been removed from the device and is enclosed.